# Delete all entries in a custom table programatically

Tags: magento2.3, repository

I'm using magento 2, I created some tables that I fill with entries then I want to delete all those entries at once.
I want the solution to use Magento repository abd without using a foreach. Something like deleteAll for example.

Thanks alot.

Comment: You can delete by database

Comment: I'm looking for a way to PROGRAMATICALLY delete records not manually.

Comment: please check my below answer maybe help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to delete all the data row from the database table then you can be used the below code to truncate the table using the model.

```
$connection = $model->getCollection()->getConnection();
$tableName = $model->getCollection()->getMainTable();
$connection->truncateTable($tableName);
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**